# how to override onBackPressed inside an if statement?

Tags: android, android-activity

My aim is to override the code of my onBackPressed method..

I have overridden the `onBackPressed` inside my `activity`

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
    this.finish();
 }
```

The code below is inside `onCreate()`, how can i override the `onBackPressed` to do something like go to another intent instead,

```
if(mode.equals("edit")){
  //onBackPressed();
}
```

**EDIT!!**
sorry for unclear question,
What i want to know is, is there a way to override the method inside to onCreate method's if statement?

Comment: what you mean by override ?

Comment: on my example if a certain condition met i want the onBackPress to do different things... but i want the code to be placed inside the if statement of onCreate(), is that even possible?

Comment: can you elaborate your scenario ?

Comment: i found out that we cannot override a method that are in same class, although this question just came from curiosity i do really appreciate the help @robodev ..

Comment: i would like to, however the answer you gave is an alternative to the desired function just like the first answer, sadly it doesnt directly answer my question.  @cafebabe1991 comment is what i need..

Comment: just set a flag in onCreate, and use it in onBackPressed. Although I don't see what prevents you from just putting that logic directly in `onBackPressed`. You do know you can call `super.onBackPressed`, right?

Comment: yes putting the logic inside the onbackpressed is the best solution, but as i mention in the above comments, this question came from my curiosity (while my java's not that great). appreciated the infos.. thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

Just do this:

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {

     // Check your mode in onBackPressed
     if(mode.equals("edit")){

         // Launch the intent
         Intent editIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
         startActivity(editIntent);

     // else call to the super class method, for default behavior 
     }else{
         super.onBackPressed();
     }
 }
```

There is nothing stopping you from making an onBackPressed call from any method in your Activity class:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            private int editMode = 1;
            private String mode = "edit";

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                 // This is totally legal to do
                 if(editMode == 1){
                       onBackPressed();
                 }
            }
    }
```

Comment: The question expects a boolean answer, "Can i override the the onBackPress or not inside an if statement", So shouldn't the answer be NO, because overriding can't be conditional ?

Comment: this solution is not wrong how ever it doesnt answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Since the method **onBackPressed()** is a **public method** You can do this:

inside onCreate(){

```
    if(mode.equals("edit")){
        onBackPressed();
    }
    else
        Log.d("dj","something else");
```

}

**in onBackPressed, i did this for testing:**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Log.d("dj", "Yeah! on back pressed");
    //super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to perform  some operation based on the calling location, 
for that I think you can follow the given below method:

```
onCreate(){
  if(Edit){
   performOperation(EDIT_OPERATION);
  }
 if(View){
  performOperation(VIEW_OPERATION);
 }
}




onBackPressed(){
    performOperation(BACKP_RESSED);
}


performOperation(int operationType){
/*
 * do operation
 */
}
```

I hope this is what you want